# result of selecting field names from table with group by

Tags: sql, select, group-by

Say you're given the following table called Customers:

```
+----+----------+-----+-----------+----------+
| ID | NAME     | AGE | ADDRESS   | SALARY   |
+----+----------+-----+-----------+----------+
|  1 | Ramesh   |  32 | Ahmedabad |  2000.00 |
|  2 | Hardik   |  25 | Delhi     |  1500.00 |
|  3 | kaushik  |  23 | Kota      |  2000.00 |
|  4 | Ramesh   |  25 | Ahmedabad |  6500.00 |
|  5 | Hardik   |  27 | Delhi     |  8500.00 |
|  6 | Komal    |  22 | MP        |  4500.00 |
|  7 | Ramesh   |  24 | Ahmedabad | 10000.00 |
+----+----------+-----+-----------+----------+
```

A lot of resources explaining group by statements would use an example like:
`SELECT NAME, SUM(SALARY) FROM CUSTOMERS GROUP BY NAME;` where the thing being 'selected' other than the field being 'grouped by' is a function like count or sum. But what happens if you did something like `SELECT NAME, ADDRESS FROM CUSTOMERS GROUP BY NAME;` - how exactly would the addresses be grouped together in a single record with the name. I know I can run this and find out the answer, but I want to understand the general logic - if anyone could assist that would be very much appreciated.

EDIT ANOTHER QUESTION:
In the new table above, if I did `SELECT NAME, ADDRESS, group_concat(salary) FROM CUSTOMERS GROUP BY NAME;` would this be ok, seeing as how the addresses are the same for each name?

Comment: Your second query should return an error -- and would in almost all databases.

Answer (score 1):

If you say `SELECT NAME, ADDRESS FROM CUSTOMERS GROUP BY NAME`, you will get an error asking you to put an aggregation function around the `ADDRESS` column. For instance, you could write

```
SELECT NAME, MAX(ADDRESS) FROM CUSTOMERS GROUP BY NAME
```

Comment: In the new table above, if I did SELECT NAME, ADDRESS, group_concat(salary) FROM CUSTOMERS GROUP BY NAME; would this be ok, seeing as how the addresses are the same for each name?